# Relation between commutator map of Lie Group and Lie Algebra

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeaiPHAh0X0), 5 minutes in, he says that the differential of the commutator map gives the tangent space a Lie algebra structure. However, the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806498/the-diffential-of-commutator-map-in-a-lie-group) clearly proves that the map is the zero map. What does he exactly mean in the video?

Comment: I don't want to see the video, but the answer of user293657 explains how you get the Lie brackets from the differential of the commutator map by taking $\epsilon$ **and** $\delta$.

Comment: You *are* familiar with the second formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Exponential_identities), no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: ? Behold the tangent space: $GHG^{-1}H^{-1}=(1\!\! 1+ \epsilon g +...) (1\!\! 1+ \delta h +...)(1\!\! 1- \epsilon g+...)(1\!\! 1- \delta h +...)= (1\!\! 1+ \epsilon \delta [g,h] +...) $. Your textbook skipped this?